# Cannot read very large data from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, postgresql

I've an application which using Leaflet reads data from GeoServer.

That GeoServer reads data from one underlying PostgreSQL database, that database has a field in one of its tables where I'm storing images via its base64 representation as the PostgreSQL datatype `text`.

Due to the representation the string to read can be very big, for example, right now I'm attempting to read one which is more than 100000 characters.

By being that big it looks like Leaflet cannot read it, and instead always uses one previosuly cached value. I've checked that if the string is shorter then it has no problem displaying the new image once it reads the base64 data from the database.

Maybe I could use some type of compression for the string and later decompress it, but I'm not sure this is always going to work, so I'd prefer to leave it as it is.

What could I do so it's possible to read such huge strings?

Due to request I'm posting code:

This is the code I use to read:

```
camping_vectorgrid.on('click', function(e) {


//addInteraction()
displayBase64Image(e.layer.properties.naamnl,e,map);
   })
  .addTo(map);
```

As long as the string in the naamnl of the database is not too large, e.layer.properties.naamnl gives the proper value (at least in zooms that are near the polygon). But if the string is too long it always uses the cached value.

Images get shown in this popup:

```
function showPopup(imagePlaceholder,e)
{
  L.popup()
        .bindPopup({maxWidth : 600})
       .setContent(imagePlaceholder)
       .setLatLng(e.latlng)
       .openOn(map);
}
```

imagePlaceholder contains the image that is generated by setting as its source its base64 representation.

Comment: Read them in what way? Which API? How is this image displayed? Seeing relevant code would help.

Comment: @TomazicM, I'll post code, anyway I think it has to do more with geoserver than with the code that reads.

Comment: What about the rest of the relevant code: layer construction, imagePlaceholder, displayBase64Image... ? What do you mean by "previosuly cached "? Cached where: server side, client side? Any errors in the browser console?  Still most of the relevant code missing. Since you know it it may seem obvious to you, but don't leave others guessing.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question, we need to know what the GeoServer log says (at GeoTools-Dev debug level) and if the string is truncated in the JSON sent to the server